# How to navigate locally opening a vpn with openfortivpn

Tags: networking, lubuntu, vpn

When I connect to the VPN all trafic is sended to the other network.

How can I set some kind of mask to send to the VPN only IP 10...* or 192.168.. ?

Currently I config

```
host = myhost.com
port = 4343
username = myname
trusted-cert = 9fc5b2d72e...
```

An I connect typing

```
sudo openfortivpn --config oficina.vpn
```

I need this to continue navigating internet with my own network and send only the inner trafic to the other network.

Comment: Can you try to add `half-internet-routes = 1` to your config file and restart the connection. I am not able to test is, but from the man page it reads as if this parameter should fix your issue.

Comment: It does not works. I try it just now.